# Why the difference in anonymous function definition syntax?

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function, function-composition

We can define and use an anonymous function like this:

```
repl=> (#(+ 10 %) 1)
11
```

But `->` macro won't accept such anonymous functions. Say I want to add 10 and then multiply by 2. I'd try to write:

```
(-> 5 #(+ 10 %) #(* 2 %))
```

But that is not the correct code for some reason, the correct code is

```
(-> 5 (+ 10) (* 2))
```

What is the difference between `(+ 10)` and `#(+ 10 %)`, and why won't `->` macro accept anonymous functions defined with `#()`?

Comment: note, that your placing of the `%` would indicate better use of the `->>` (thread last).  it makes no difference for `+` and `*` but could with other functions.  also you can just "call" your `#()` in the thread macro to make it work: `(-> 5 (#(+ 10 %)) (#(* 2 %)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my attempt at an explanation. There are two parts.

First, the anonymous literal syntax. When you write `#(+ 10 %)`, it gets expanded into something that is functionally similar to the following:

```
(fn [x] (+ 10 x))
```

For ex.

```
=> (macroexpand '(#(+ 10 %))
```

Would return something like:

```
(fn* [p1__7230#] (+ 10 p1__7230#))
```

The second part. When you use the threading macro, as the [docs say](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1564), the macro expands by inserting the first argument as the **second item** into the first form. And if there are more forms, inserts the first form as the  **second item** in second form, and so on.

The key term here is *second item*. It doesn't care about what forms you are providing as arguments, it will just do an expansion using that rule.

So, to combine both the points, when you use

```
(-> 5 #(+ 10 %) #(* 2 %))
```

following the rules, it gets expanded into something that is functionally similar to this

```
(fn (fn 5 [x] (+ 10 x)) [y] (* 2 y))
```

which doesn't compile.

Also, as a side note, the form `(+ 10)` is not an anonymous function. It is a partial function call that gets updated with arguments during macro expansion. And by 'partial', I mean in the literal sense, not in the functional programming sense.

*Update*

To explain why it works when you enclose the anonymous literal within parentheses (as a comment on the question says), you can infer the results from these two rules. For ex.

```
 => (macroexpand '(#(+ 10 %)))
```

would result in the functional equivalent of

```
((fn [x] (+ 10 x)))
```

So, when an item is inserted in its *second* place, it would look like

```
((fn [x] (+ 10 x)) 5)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
(#(+ 10 %) 5)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `macro-expand` to demonstrate reader syntax (which `#(..)` is). You can use even a stage earlier: `(read-string "#(foo %)")`.